# How to handle intermittent missing visits in marginal structural model?

Tags: causality, missing-data, censoring, marginal-model

The reference papers for marginal structural models only talked about handling monotone censoring using IPCW.
How to deal with intermittent missing visits? Does it make sense to use available visits only and multiplying the weights of available visits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you won't want to only use the available visits as you describe.

Most work transforms the data into monotone missingness, as it is easier to work with. To do this, you would censor someone when they miss a visit for all subsequent visits. Depending on the number of intermittent missing visits, this can result in a substantial amount of missing data. So whether to use this approach depends on how many observations will be available at the final time point.

A more recent proposed alternative is IPW for nonmonotonic missing / censoring. These weights are described in [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5860553/) and a more technical discussion in [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6051732/). I know someone who is doing simulation work on this estimator but it is not published yet (can follow up once it is). In that work, they find that the UMLE works fine in most settings  (i.e., you don't have to implement the Bayesian version).

Comment: Thanks for the reference papers. I read the less technical one so far. Looks like it is straightforward to implement with a bunch of logistic regressions corresponding to different missing data patterns. Although model mis-specification is an always concern, it seems better than artificially censoring the data to monotone missing.

Comment: Note that the logistic models have to be estimated simultaneously (not individually). So, you will most likely have to write your own log-likelihood to implement (there may be software or code somewhere out there but I am unaware of any).

Comment: Really?! Thanks for pointing it out. I was not aware of that, since the parameters in equation (8) of the less technical paper are all distinct. I wonder if you can use multinomial logistic model to solve for the parameters in equation (10) by setting the missing covariates to 0. It seems the 4 missing patterns are like 4 mutually exclusive categories.

Comment: The reason they are estimated together is that we are getting the probability of a complete-case by subtracting the probabilities of all other cases from 1. We also can't use a multinomial model for implementation (to my knowledge). Each model includes covariates that are missing from others, and setting the missing covariates to zero will change the estimated probabilities of each model (we can't set to zero because the true covariate value may not be zero). These difficulties is why the monotonic data approach remains pretty popular (despite losing some information).